# Leaflet extend GeoJSON component giving issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm going to extend GeoJSON component from leaflet to create a custom component I'm using leaflet 1.6.0 with typescript and follow the steps given by leaflet documentation(https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#class) but getting issue when creating the new custom component object 'Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)'. My custom component implementation as follows.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { useLeaflet, GeoJSON } from "react-leaflet";
import L from 'leaflet';
import uuid from "react-uuid";

import { BoundaryMarkContext } from '../MapsPage';
import { getStyle} from '../../style';

type Props = {
    featureCollection: any;
};

const CustomGeoJson = (props: Props) => {
    var keyForFeatureCollection = uuid();
    const boundaryMarkChangeDetails = useContext(BoundaryMarkContext);

    const onEachFeature = (feature, layer) => {
        layer.on('click', function (e) {
            boundaryMarkChangeDetails.handleBoundaryMarkClick(e)
        });
    }

    const boundaryMarkPointToLayer = (feature, latlng) => {

      };

    const GeoJsonExtend =  L.GeoJSON.extend({
        options: {
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
            pointToLayer: boundaryMarkPointToLayer,
            style: getStyle
        },

        initialize: function(data, key) {
            this.data = data;
            this.key = key;
        }
    });

    return new GeoJsonExtend({ data: props.featureCollection, key: keyForFeatureCollection });
    
};

export default CustomGeoJson;
```

Comment: What line is causing that error?  TS should tell you exactly what function expects 0 arguments but got 1

Comment: @SethLutske this line ` return new GeoJsonExtend({ data: props.featureCollection, key: keyForFeatureCollection });` gives the error